# Why is CDATA needed for html in jQuery AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, cdata

I have an ajax function that returns an xml. In the xml there is one html table and some other xml elements. I tried a few ways to extract the html table for inserting into the page, but was told that I need to wrap the table with CDATA. Then I can use the `$container.html(respose.find('table-data').text())` to make it work.

What I want to ask are:

1. Is this the only way to do this?
2. Why is CDATA needed? I thought xhtml should co-exists with xml nicely.

EDIT:

Here is my xml response, I have checked with Firebug and is valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<response>
  <data>
    <li class="item x1">
       <p class="l1"><b class="view">0 views</b></p>
    </li>
    <li class="item x2">
      <p class="l1"><b class="view">0 views</b></p>
    </li>
  </data>
  <total_count>101387</total_count>
  <total_pages>4056</total_pages>
  <pagesize>25</pagesize>
</response>
```

Comment: Show us a sample XML document including HTML *without* CDATA.  Then, we can check whether it's valid XML.  Actually, you can do so yourself if you want. :)

Comment: yep I have already checked and it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

**CDATA** sections are commonly used for scripting language content and sample XML and HTML content.
Check for more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076.aspx

Try with `jQuery.parseXML`
more details http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ and this Complete Code http://www.vagrantradio.com/2009/10/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery-and-ajax.html